# Cordova-CLI and Icons (aren't included)

Tags: android, ios, cordova, icons

I'm using Cordova CLI 4.2.1 in my project, but I'm unable to get icons working. I've put all the icons [as described in the docs](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.4.0/config_ref_images.md.html#Icons%20and%20Splash%20Screens) into `www/res/icons`. *(Note: Due to the documentation the folder should have already existed with the defaults icons in it, but there wasn't any folder in my projected created via the CLI)*

But the icons aren't copied into the bundle after building the app. When searching the web I found a lot of links saying to manually copy them into the projects. This may work but this is pain since this would get done after every build.

Another link on the web told me to add `<icon src="res/icons/" />` to my `config.xml` but this doesn't helped too.

*(Another note: The project is created like described [in the docs](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.4.0/guide_cli_index.md.html#The%20Command-Line%20Interface) and is just bare bone. So there shouldn't be anything else preventing this from working.)*

Comment: I know the documentation is not very clear, but this is only for the PhoneGap Build service. For Cordova, you have to place these yourself after installing each platform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was previously using phonegap CLI (3.0 till 3.3) and www/res/icons were here when creating new project but actually not copied to the platforms when creating platform or building. Actually they were used only for phonegap build.

I'm now using cordova 3.4 and www/res is no more created.

The default icons are created by the cli when you add the platform to the project. You can change the icons after you add the platform, the CLI will not touch them when you build, so you only have to to it once for each platform.

Comment: Tried it and it the cordova-cli doesn't touch the icons in the `platforms` you are right. Thanks. It works, but I'm not happy how Cordova has solved that. It would be better if developers won't ever touch anything in the platforms directory. (I would expect it to get recreated on a new build.)

Comment: agree. You can try to submit an issue to the devs.

Answer (score 0):

The `res/icons` folder and files are only for the PhoneGap Build service. With Cordova you manually add these after installing the platform to your project.

For iOS you use the functionality that Xcode provides.

For Android you add them in `platforms/android/res/drawable` and additionally to the other `drawable-XXX` folders if you wish to support the various display types.